# Memory leak is happening when writing to file on AIX

Tags: c++, aix

I have the following function which is used to write logs, it is part of a program which runs on several operating systems including Windows and AIX. The problem is that it is causing a memory leak when run on AIX, a constant memory increase is happening which is not the case if I simply removed the code, specifically the `fwrite` call.

```
void print_msg(char* header, char* msg)
{
   string buffer = "-------\n";
   buffer.append(header);
   buffer.append(msg);
   buffer.append("\n------\n");

   fwrite(buffer.c_str(), sizeof(char), buffer.length(), pFile);
   fflush(pFile);
}
```

The file is opened when the program starts, and closed before the program is terminated.

It worth to mention that I am using the following command to monitor the memory consumption of the program:

```
svmon -P <process_id> -O summary=basic,unit=MB
```

Sample output of `svmon` command which I run randomly every few seconds:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    251.34     37.1     9.98   121.73
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    368.27     37.1     9.98   238.66
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    479.12     37.1     9.98   349.51
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    483.56     37.1     9.98   350.09
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    485.14     37.1     9.98   350.09
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    486.57     37.1     9.98   350.09
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    491.15     37.1     9.98   350.09
-----------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    494.87     37.1     9.98   350.09
------------------------------------------------
Pid         Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual
10158210    496.44     37.1     9.98   350.09
```

The question is: what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I can only suggest profiling it with memory detection tool. Looks like a problem with AIX implementation, unless you are not giving us the full truth here.

Comment: Can you reproduce the leak with this fumction and a simple main() tbat calls it 1000000 times?

Comment: @n.m. I didn't try that to be honest.

Comment: @SergeyA Why would I hide anything? I tried as much as I can to minimize the problem so that it is clear for everyone. If you have any questions, I have no problem to answer them.

Comment: You might think it is not significant enough. Can you isolate the problem in the self-contained MCVE? If you can, post the MCVE. If you can't, this is a strong hint something else is at play here.

Comment: @SergeyA I am working on that.